# Mysql server Gone Away

Tags: php, mysql

I got "MySQL server gone away" error, i also got the resource id & connection also created successfully. Really don't know what's going wrong.

below is my code..

```
$query ='select * from table';
if (!@mysql_ping($conn)) {
    conn = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD) or die("Unable to connect with server");
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE,$conn) or die("Unable to select database");
    mysql_query($query) or mysql_error($conn);
}
```

Any help? i miss something in or i need to set up some config file?

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Comment: Is the MySQL server on Localhost? If not, do you have the correct hostname and is the firewall (if any) allowing connections? Is it running?

Comment: And `table` is a reserved keyword. Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html for a full list. You could change your query to: `select * from \`table\``

Comment: Normally this error is due to unable to connect to MySQL server.

Comment: table = "reservation" & I am run it on server using cron.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor k thnx i will check it..

Comment: I'd recommend not suppressing errors using `@`.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor just resolve the issue 

if (!@mysql_ping($conn)) {
                            mysql_close($conn);
                            $conn = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD) or die("Unable to connect with server");
                            echo 'connection created--' . $conn . '---<br/>';
//                            exit();
                            mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $conn) or die("Unable to select database" . mysql_error($conn));
                        } 
ANd i changes the code to Mysqli ,thnx 4 d hint.

Comment: you can answer your question below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        if (!@mysql_ping($conn)) {
            mysql_close($conn);
            $conn = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD) or die("Unable to connect with server");
            echo 'connection created--' . $conn . '---<br/>'; 
            mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $conn) or die("Unable to select database" . mysql_error($conn));
        }
```

Comment: i think this is the code as you want to say @kiranjoshi